# What's wrong with tee command?

Tags: command-line, bash, python

I am running the following `python` script `piped` to `tee` command

```py
#!/usr/bin/python

from sys import exit,exc_info
from time import sleep

try:
    print "hello"
    #raise KeyboardInterrupt
    while True:
        print "hello"
        sleep(1)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print "Key board Interrupt"
    exit(0)
```

Let's say I stored this in `file.py`

Now if I execute:

```
./file.py | tee somefile
```

Now press `Ctrl+C`, observe nothing is printed into the `somefile` and `stdout`

Under normal execution:

```
./file.py
```

Upon `Ctrl+C`:

```
 hello
 hello
 ^CKey board Interrupt
```

Also file redirection is working fine. What's wrong with `tee`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nothing's wrong with `tee`. Python buffers output if it detects it's not writing to a TTY. See [this Unix & Linux post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/182541/70524). Use `sys.stdout.flush()` to force flushing the buffer.

Comment: In Python 3 you can use `print('hello', flush=True)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this way as well:

```
python -u file.py | tee somefile
```

This problem mentioned on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21662783/linux-tee-is-not-working-with-python)

Comment: Works for Python3